# Travis yml error

Tags: git, travis-ci

I am trying to set up my travis.yml file so that by default if the branch is not master the files get uploaded to /var/www/test but if the branch is master they get uploaded to /var/www/html. I've seen that using conditionals in the .yml file is possible, reference [this post in the Travis Docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/). I have made the following .travis.yml file but when I validate it using [Travis WebLint](https://lint.travis-ci.org/) it comes up with this error: syntax error: (): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 9 column 8

Any ideas?

```
language: generic  
env:
 global:
 - "FTP_USER=user"
 - "FTP_PASSWORD=password"
 - "FTP_DIR=/var/www/test"

if: branch = master
 env: FTP_DIR=/var/www/html/

after_success:
 "curl --ftp-create-dirs -T uploadfilename -u $FTP_USER:$FTP_PASSWORD ftp://<hidden>$FTP_DIR"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maintain different .travis.yml in different branches. In master:

```
env:
 global:
 - "FTP_USER=user"
 - "FTP_PASSWORD=password"
 - "FTP_DIR=/var/www/html"
```

And in test:

```
env:
 global:
 - "FTP_USER=user"
 - "FTP_PASSWORD=password"
 - "FTP_DIR=/var/www/test"
```

Be careful with merges.

Comment: How can I have different .travis.yml files for different branches within just one repo?

Comment: I thought it was possible to have conditionals in the file https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/conditional-builds-stages-jobs/

Comment: The same way you have other different files in different branches. Edit — add — commit — switch branch — edit — add — commit.

Comment: Ah right makes sense, how would I stop it from merging though

Comment: So in the .gitattributes file I would just have .travis.yml and I would set that config option for git?

Comment: If I decided to have 2 branches, master and test, would the if conditions work then?

Comment: The `if:` syntax is for stages, not global. See examples in the Travis docs.